# Replacement/Copy of 70s Honda Key

Tags: honda, motorcycle, key, ignition-key, cb750

I bought a 1972 Honda CB750 and the key that came with it is a weird little key. I'm guessing this is the way they were made back then. I would really like to get a copy of the key so I have more than one but no locksmith around here can do anything with it.

One of the locksmiths suggested that this may be a factory key that they made that I may be able to buy other copies of online (it doesn't look like a very complex/specific key pattern). The problem is I can't seem to find this key anywhere. I suppose I'd be alright replacing the ignition but I'd love to keep it OEM if possible.

Any ideas on where I could get my hands on another one of these (or how I could get it copied)?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if that is an OEM key and possibly your ignition has been replaced.  The old clunker CB 250 I have from early seventies has flutes.  But maybe mine is the non OEM.

Comment: Why not take a mold of it and cast a key?

Comment: Regarding molding - thought I remember that there was an app that would take a picture of the key and you could then send it to a fab who would 3D print it?  Don't remember the app - so not submitting this as an answer.  I seem to recall a mini panic about it since you could take pictures even fairly off-angle and at a distance.

Comment: @Blackbeagle That actually sounds really interesting.

Comment: Yeah both are great ideas. It sounds like the ignition is not OEM so I may just end up replacing it. I bought this bike mainly to work on it and try to restore some parts of it. I've never worked on a bike before so I'm just tinkering away so I'll likely just try to find an original part and replace this ignition entirely...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to matchup keys only based on a picture. In my travels, I did find several Ilco blank keys that are similar in appearance to yours, I even found a few places that sell them online. It looks like a lot of non-interchangeable keys were used on Honda motorcycles of that era, even for the same model and year.

[This site](http://www.keys4urride.com/honda-c-18.html) has a lot of Honda motorcycle keys with pictures.
[If you download this file](http://www.ilco.us/media/853752/v5/File/key-blank-directory-03-vehicle-sec-1.pdf), you can also browse all the Ilco blank keys that are listed for Honda motorcycles.

All the blanks I'm seeing have a groove in them, nothing flat like yours. Your best bet would be to list the close matches based on these and then find somebody local to you that has those blanks in stock so you can physically compare your key to the blank.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great help, I'll investigate further now.

Comment: For looking at this, I'm not seeing anything close to my key in the Honda Motorcycle section. I'm wondering if it's possible if they swapped the ignition lock out or something? Would there be a way to determine based on the model of the ignition?

Comment: @MillerMedia in the 70-80s you would find ignition switch replacements at the motorcycle shops and car parts stores.  They we cheaper knockoff  made units made in various places in asia area. Most had simple blank with simple cuts.

Comment: @spicetraders so you're saying my ignition is most likely just a cheap knockoff (not OEM)?

Comment: @MillerMedia IMHO it does not match any keys that I see by searches for a 1972 OEM key and does not match the OEM keys I have had in the past.  If any thing it looks more like a side cover key.  A cheap knock off or extremely warn OEM I can only make a WAG at.

Comment: That's a nice pdf of keys.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely not an OE key. OE keys from the 70s are professionally made by the factory and have plastic/rubber grips. That is in all likelihood a handmade key from a locksmith, which in my opinion is actually cooler.

You can have a mobile motorcycle locksmith come out to your house and make you a new one right out of the ignition, or take that key to a locksmith and they will cut you a copy. Pick whichever internet key blank you choose, but go to a real locksmith, not a home improvement store.